# What request to use to update resource without sending data

Tags: http, post, get, request, patch

every now and then I come to this question, google around for some time without getting a definitive answer and let it be.

Problem:

I want to update an existing resource, but the logic how this update works is on the backend side.

Let's assume a product should only be visible for a set time. Keeping it simple. The time "from" is stored in the database along the product data: product.visibleFromDate and the duration (eg. 30 days) is just a variable or configured somewhere (not in DB).

Now I want to call the backend telling it to update the visibleFromDate to "now": /api/product/:id/updatevisibility
In this case I don't want to send a body because the server should determine what value "now" really is.

I actually don't really care if the server answers with the updated resource or no content.

HTTP Request

GET

- Should not be used because it should be idempotent, which it wouldn't be because the visibleFromDate would be updated

POST

- Don't want to send the date from frontend

PUT

- Don't want to send the date from frontend + should be idempotent

PATCH

- Merge Patch: Don't want to send the date from frontend
- JSON Patch: Again, I don't want to send a value, I want the backend to determine it.

Of course I could just send an empty object, the whole resource or some nonsense and ignore it on the backend side, but still I feel like I am missing this "trigger" type of requests which only need the type of resource, id and action.

Comment: I came to the conclusion you will not satisfy with any answer because you yourself haven't yet formed an image of an acceptable answer in your own mind. It now sounds more like just a rhetorical question "why did you do that!? oh, never mind, I don't care".

Comment: It seems you take it personally and I did not intend that. I now accepted the most vague answer since it is the only one not directly suggesting to do something that is contrary to the spec. I dunno why you would blame me for not accepting answers that say "do a" if it clearly states in the spec that a is not the right thing to do. Yes, sometimes I try to find the "perfect" answer, mostly to understand the problem and why the spec is as it is. In this case nobody could answer it, but they suggested to ignore the spec, which in my mind is not really professional.

Comment: I can't request that you read all my comments on other answers, but I acknowledged multiple times that using PATCH and sending '{}' may be the best solution, even though I still think it does not fit 100%. Is this what you call rejecting? I am clearly rejecting answers that go against the spec and I will continue to do so. If you are not conforming to e.g. google maps API it will not work because you have to conform to the spec behind the API. Just because it is technically possible in this case it absolutely no reason to do it. You spent a lot of time, so thank you. But my point stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the mutability of the data it should either be POST(immutable) or PATCH(mutable). It doesn't depend on what You're sending or not sending.
If You really want to do it by the book then you should send a `'{}'` when there are no fields to send. If any is added later you will just add it like `'{"duration":"30"}'`

Comment: Why would the mutability of the data matter? I guess an empty object or `{}` with a `POST` is the "cleanest" solution, sadly.

Comment: @clash It matters only as a best practice and cleanliness type of rule. When using POST You're either inserting a new object or replacing a whole object with a new one. and when using patch You're just changing a few fields. This helps immensely when dealing with concurrency and dependencies.

Comment: https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#POST Doesn't read like what you are saying, but I get what you are saying, still think a trigger request type is missing...

Answer (score 1):

You would definitely want POST over GET for authorization/authentication purposes.

You don't need to have a body for a POST request. Your endpoint will just listen for a request, it will extract `:id`, and then run your time update function.

PUT and PATCH are semantic equivalents to POST. Unless you programmed the backend to differentiate them, there won't be any difference. You don't even need them at all.

A single empty-body POST will be enough for your endpoint. But you may consider using empty-body PATCH just as a meaningful endpoint. In both cases, your backend will extract the `:id` and then just run the same function (after auth* if any)

---

EDIT: Seems not all people can grasp what I have, so here are a working nodejs/express backend and curl requests to use. you don't need a request body, and all behave the same, except semantics and security over GET.

this is the server code:

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = 3000

const updatetime = async (id)=>{
 let newdate=Date.now();
 console.log(`updating resource ${id} to have a new date ${newdate}`);
 return Promise.resolve("done")
}

const processrequest=async (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.method);
 console.log(req.headers);
 console.log(req.headers.authorization);
 console.log(req.body)
 console.log(req.params)
  try{
    let result=await updatetime(req.params.id);
    console.log(result);
    res.status(200).send("time updated")
  }catch{
    res.status(500).send("something went wrong")
  }
}

app.get(  '/:id/updatetime', (req, res) => processrequest(req,res))
app.post( '/:id/updatetime', (req, res) => processrequest(req,res))
app.put(  '/:id/updatetime', (req, res) => processrequest(req,res))
app.patch('/:id/updatetime', (req, res) => processrequest(req,res))


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

test all endpoint without a body, all works because magic:

```bash
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic" localhost:3000/123qwe/updatetime
time updated
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic" localhost:3000/123qwe/updatetime
time updated
curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Basic" localhost:3000/123qwe/updatetime
time updated
curl -X PATCH -H "Authorization: Basic" localhost:3000/123qwe/updatetime
time updated
```

server output for all request types are the same because it is just a magic(!) that is developers' choice of implementation:

```
listening on port 3000
GET/POST/PUt/PATCH
{
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  'user-agent': 'curl/7.78.0',
  accept: '*/*',
  authorization: 'Basic'
}
Basic
undefined
{ id: '123qwe' }
updating resource 123qwe to have a new date 1656495470330
done
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST -> "Request has body": "Yes". The POST method exists for sending data to a server. By definition and specification, sending an empty body with a POST is wrong. Also, some frameworks and libs need a body for a POST request (Angular comes to mind). Also, what does POST or GET have to do with auth?

Comment: @clash, I have added working node-express app you can start working right away. unless the programming language does not permit, you are free to supply body or not. and auth with POST/GET are the same unless you care.

Comment: Thanks but this was a hypothetical question. The technical implementation is no problem for me. But with these kind of situations I want to be as close to the standard/spec as possible. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @clash, the question is hypothetical and the code is a proof of concept showing the differences. but if you want a "standard" then your question is no more hypothetical and the code helps to differentiate. and there is no standard use other than the semantic definitions because it all comes down to the developers' interpretation. if you really want, instead of requiring "opinions" of others, just stick to definitions of these methods (why they were invented) and apply them to your work. If you want a "partial update" then use PATCH. that's it.

Comment: That is my problem, the definitions don't match the given situation.

Comment: @clash I don't think "the definitions don't match the given situation" is true. and it is rather "your interpretation of definitions do not match the situation". I would suggest you create use cases for every single possibility but that would take a long time to cover them all. yet if you try to do such, you will see it is an "opinionated" path and realize what you need is not a solid answer but some way of "best practices"

Comment: Me saying POST must have a body is not an interpretation, it is part of the spec. People saying you can send an empty body is maybe an interpretation. But it is more wrong than right. It is "right" only because it is technically possible (but as mentioned, there are frameworks/libs which try to prevent this). Sending an empty JSON object is just a work around. I was hoping for "the one answer", but it seems this topic can only be opinionated. That said, I will not accept an answer that goes against the spec in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to pass a body in a request (Although the specification says so), PATCH will be your best option here since semantically it is updating an “part of existing resource” while PUT is meant for "updating the entire resource".

Comment: Technically you are not required to include a body, but the specification says so. But I agree, PATCH is probably the most accurate way of handling this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

my other answer did not satisfy you, so i will try the same but from a different viewpoint.

you are data engineer:

- you don't retrieve any data with this operation, so no GET.
- you operate on already-existing data, so no POST.
- you don't change the whole data, so no PUT.
- you are partially changing the data, see, you just use PATCH for the operation.
- you will send an empty body `{}` to be consistent

you are an operational backend engineer.

- GET is still considered to be used to retrieve a resource.
- you want to run a function on the server which will partially modify the resource having the id given as the parameter in the url, so just use a POST request. it is like calling a function in your programming language.
- or try PATCH to get the sympathy of your users.
- or use PUT to get their anger when they realized what happens.
- it is already getting the id from the URL, so you don't have to send any body unless your frontend API forces. `curl` won't send a body if you don't give one, for example.

semantics are not hard-coded rules. they are there to guide you and keep you in the line as much as possible. the problem is that they don't have solid implementation details. they are also "opinions" of a group of people which has pretty fine shape anyone can accept.

---

PS: It is said, "POST can be used on an already-existing data to append". sure it is, but the question in scope asks about changing a field, not creating a new one.

Comment: As mentioned in other comments: I get what you are saying, still I think all these solutions are work-arounds for something missing in the spec. My problem with "developers interpretations" is that there are infinite interpretations. Every team I worked in handles these kind of situations differently, each with positives and drawbacks. So: there must be something missing here. e.g. You say - don't use POST for existing data. The spec says a use case can be "Appending data to a resource's existing representation(s)". In my opinion your interpretation is wrong.

Comment: @clash, POST for appending, acceptable. but remember you are not appending anything, you are changing an existing field.